# Convert coordinates from a skewed system to ortho-canonical (2D).

Tags: geometry

First of all, I am not a mathematician so please excuse my novice way of describing the problem at hand...

I have several sets of data which represent x,y coordinates in various skewed/oblique systems, and I want to convert them all to a common ortho-canonical system, in order to later "stack" them on top of each other in a single plot. Let's assume a skewed system is as shown here:

[Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Qnv.png)

where (x,y) the coordinates of a point in this systen, (a,b) the origin, φ the angle between the x and y axes (<>90 degrees), and θ the angle between the x axis and the horizontal plane. I can calculate the angle φ from known points within the axes, and I think I can also calculate θ.

From my research so far, I believe this transformation needs to happen in 3 steps:

1. Make the x axis horizontal (eliminate the θ angle).
2. Make the φ angle 90 degrees (make the y axis vertical).
3. Move the axes origin to a common point for all data sets (e.g. 0,0).

So basically, I need the equations for each of these steps.

A similar question was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62752/1270172)

which offers the equations for the 2nd step, but I have not been able to successfully complete the first step, in order to check if these equations work correctly.

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).